# Label in UserControl (Winforms) don't show

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

Have a UserControl with a Label, a homebrew "TextBox" (inherited directly from Control) and a Button.
The goal is to have the label "glued" to the relevant controls, so the design of forms is more straightforward.
I overrided the OnPaint() event, so the witdh of the "TextBox" is computed taking into account the width of the label. Which in turn have its text taken from a designable property of the UserControl. This way, the full width of the UserControl is what is seen in the designer.
All computing is correctly done (when the text for the label is bigger, the text width is lesser, and viceversa... ). More again: if the label text is empty, the label is marked as no visible, and the like.
But the label is not shown. 
Some ideas?
TIA

Comment: Did you add the TextBox in the parent control?

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the code for your custom control.

Comment: Look at it in the debugger! often the location is off..

Comment: I'm logging the Location (Left and Top in the case of Label) values for the full UserControl, the "TextBox" and the Label. They are all congruent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed Shell's advice. But with a twist.
If you try to DrawString() from the UserControl OnPaint event, nohing happens, because the OnPaint for the form is triggered after all control's, so it wipes out the text.
What I resorted to was to create a method in the Form in wich the UserControl is contained and set it as an interface. Some code follows

The interface and auxiliary class

```
public interface IKindForm
{
    void DisplayText( DisplayText t );
}

public class DisplayText
{
    public string Text { get; protected set; }
    public Font Font { get; protected set; }
    public Brush Brush { get; protected set; }
    public Point Point { get; protected set; }

    public DisplayText( string text, Font font, Color color, int x, int y )
    {
        Text = text;
        Font = font;
        Brush = new SolidBrush( color );
        Point = new Point( x, y );
    }
}
```

The method in the form which implements the interface and the overrided OnPaint

```
    private List<DisplayText> textsToDisplay = new List<DisplayText>();

    public void DisplayText( DisplayText t )
    {
        if (textsToDisplay.Contains( t ))
            return;
        textsToDisplay.Add( t );
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint( PaintEventArgs e )
    {
        foreach (DisplayText t in textsToDisplay)
            e.Graphics.DrawString( t.Text, t.Font, t.Brush, t.Point );
        base.OnPaint( e );
    }
```

And finally, the code in the UserControl

```
    bool labelRegistered = false;

    protected override void OnPaint( PaintEventArgs e )
    {

        int textStart = 0;
        SizeF ssize = new SizeF( 0, 0 );

        if (labelText != null && labelText != String.Empty) {
            ssize = e.Graphics.MeasureString( labelText, labelFont );
            textStart = (int)ssize.Width;
        }

       if (ssize.Width > 0) {
            if (this.TopLevelControl is IKindForm) {
                if (!labelRegistered) {
                    int yPos = this.Location.Y + margin + ComboText.Size.Height / 4;
                    int xPos = this.Location.X - ( textStart + labelOffset );
                    ((IKindForm)this.TopLevelControl).DisplayText( new DisplayText(    labelText, LabelFont, labelColor,
                                                                                     xPos, yPos ) );
                }
            }
            labelRegistered = true;
        }
```

Only drawback is that when in designer, the TopLevelControl is not a IKindForm one, so you cannot see the "label".

Comment: Well if it works.. But this looks __awfully complicated__ just for displaying a Label..!

Comment: Not if you need lots of input fields and their labels. The ability to "glue" the label to the field (also, it becomes possible to change colors programmatically) and so, move them in the designer freely.

Comment: I'm embarked in a large project, which requires (among other things) that input controls be full managed with keystrokes. This "twist" is a minor nuance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add the label in user control inherited by textbox. you have to place both control(label and textbox) separately on user control instead of inheriting. thus, you can set the textbox's size and location programatically. and you have to create all properties which you want to handle outside the class or namespace.

for example

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
[Browsable(true)]
[DefaultValue(string.Empty)]
public override string Text
{
    get {
        return txtBox.Text;
    }
    set {
        txtBox.Text  = value;
    }
}

[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
[Browsable(true)]
[DefaultValue("My Lable:")]    
public string LabelText
{
    get{
        return lblLabel.Text;
    }
    Set {
        lblLabel.Text = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I don't spelled it well: of course, the usercontrol has three separate controls: the Label, my homebrew TextBox, and a standard Button.

Comment: Why don't u Draw a string instead of placing a label control. thus, you can measure string correctly and locate the textbox correctly.